# Opera - How to make it run faster?

Tags: performance, cpu-usage, opera

I'm using Opera version 12.13 under Windows XP home. 
It needs ~50% of my CPU and it takes a few seconds if open or close a tab. How can I make it run faster and if possible with less CPU usage?

I have usually around 10-20 tabs open, no RSS feeds, no Email or chats, no synchronization, no extensions and I enable plug-ins only on demand.
This are my current history settings:

[image: Opera history settings.]

Thanks for your tips.

Comment: Maybe just wait for next version - Opera is switching to Webkit, the same engine that's used in Chrome and Safari. It may work better.

Comment: @Sam: You could try 12.14 that is already out in case it is something that has gotten fixed. Try to pinpoint the issue on a specific page or something. This should not be normal behavior (unless your computer has very low specs, in which case any browser would probably behave like this on the system). Check your memory usage - perhaps it is maxed out and Opera is using the swap file. If that is the case, you can't do much else than perhaps upgrading your available RAM size or cutting down on other applications that are running simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may not be the Opera's fault. You should check if there are any processes running in the background, that could also use much CPU power. Check also if you have at least 15 - 20 % of free space on your system drive/partition (Where the operating system is installed), as programs also gets slower as the hard drive contains more data.

Hope it helped. Comment your results, so eventually I can help you if these didn't fix the problem